# How can I train Thunderbird's spam filter?

Tags: thunderbird, spam-prevention

Thunderbird spam filter works **pretty well** but for some reason, mails from "**Approved VIAGRA Store**" continually get through and are not marked as spam even when I continually mark them as junk.

Is there a way I can add to a **black list** the phrase "Approved VIAGRA Store" so that it will mark it as junk?

**Does Thunderbird have a simple black and white list that I could edit or is there an extension to do this?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One tedious, per account, way would be to set up a filter matching that phrase and marking emails with it as junk.

> Tools > Message Filters

Select the account you want to set the filter for. (This is the tedious part because this method isn't something you can currently apply globally.)

Click **New...**

Give your filter a name.

In the filter rules, set:

```
For incoming messages that:
Body: contains: Approved VIAGRA Store
```

```
Perform these actions:
Set Junk status to: Junk
```

Click **OK** to save and close out.

Now, incoming mail will be filtered for that and marked accordingly if it matches the rule.

Answer (score 2):

Install [Junquilla](http://mesquilla.com/extensions/junquilla/) and you can see an analysis of exactly why a message was marked spam or not spam.

Answer (score 0):

I cam across this Addon for Thunderbird that seems to have great ratings and has more advanced features for [spam control](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/emailsecurityplus/?src=search) called email security plus. It's great cause it allows you to add blacklist emails and helps train the Thunderbird system a bit better.